# How to use string functions in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to convert a string to upper case in pig using one of it's built-in functions. I am using pig in local mode.

## emps.csv

```
1,John,35,M,101,50000.00,03/03/79
2,Jack,30,F,201,3540000.00,09/10/84
```

## Commands for loading data (WORKS FINE)

```
empdata = load 'emps.csv'  using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,name:chararray,age:int,gender:chararray,deptId:int,sal:double);
dump empdata
```

## Convert to upper case and print it (FAILS WITH ERROR)

```
empnameucase = foreach empdata generate id,upper(name);
```

But I am getting following exception after executing above command:

## Error Log:

```
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve upper using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
        at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:653)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.getClassForAlias(PigContext.java:769)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildUDF(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1491)
        ... 28 more
```

Please guide.

Comment: Look at the error: `Could not resolve upper`. What are you expecting `upper(name)` to do?

Comment: Expectation is that it should convert name to upper case. To be specific Jack should be displayed as JACK.

Comment: What leads you to expect that? Where did you find a command with that name?

Comment: Got it :) It's case sensitive. I should be using UPPER instead of upper. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
You should specify the function name in UPPER case like

```
UPPER(name)
```

Hopt,it should work.